# Faster "parsing" of float numbers: avoid conversion from and back to string

Tags: performance, json.net

I have a huge JSON file (1.4 GB) and it contains mainly float values.

From what I can see in the profiler, it seems that JSON.NET first parses the JSON file into float values and later converts the float values into strings for displaying them. That takes 31 seconds - which I want to reduce.

[image: Screenshot]

FYI: I can hardly do something against the 37 seconds. It's mainly parsing the JSON.

For my purposes, I don't need the float values, so these values could just remain strings, since I only want to display them.

Is that possible in JSON.NET, e.g. by deriving from JsonConverter? The examples online were not very helpful for this case.

I have tried:

- [FloatParseHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_FloatParseHandling.htm), but it can only toggle between double and decimal

Comment: To ignore floats, the deserialiser needs to know that a certain value is of a float type, and for that it would have to at least `TryParse` it.